# Series sum - where is the error?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}k + \sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}(-k)+ 2N$$

The should sum up to: $2N-N^2$.

I however obtain different result, by proceeding as follows:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}k = \frac{(N-1)N}{2}$$

$$\sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}(-k) = -\frac{(N-1)(3N-1)}{2}$$

There is a good chance that the one immediately above is incorrect. Here is how I have came up with it. There are $2N-1-N$ values in between $2N-1$ and $N$, therefore following that Gauss's little trick, we sum up $N-1$ lots of $2N-1+N$, i.e. $3N-1$; but since we are doubling (are we?) the sum, we divide by $2$.

Now all this together gives:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}k + \sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}(-k)+ 2N = \frac{(N-1)N}{2}-\frac{(N-1)(3N-1)}{2}+\frac{4N}{2} \neq 2N-N^2$$

Simply because there is a half in the middle term that will not vanish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}(-k)=-\sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}k$$

The number of terms are $n=2N-1-N+1=N$

$$\sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}k=\dfrac N2\cdot\{2N+(N-1)\cdot1\}=\dfrac{N(3N-1)}2$$

Comment: I had a minus in my answer here on the paper... Sorry. Even if I include a minus above, I don't get that answer. I cann see that your sum is different though.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I survived up to now, ignoring one term... Thanks!

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal, Your sum $$\sum_{k=N}^{2N-1}(-k)$$ is wrong. Please focus on the method. The result should follow

Comment: Yeah, got it now!

Answer (score 1):

The second sum, the one you had a doubt on is
$$-\frac{N(3N-1)}{2}$$

The number of terms is $N$ not $N-1$. And you forgot the sign.